# How does one find out one's own Repo ID?

Tags: github, repository

While I definitely am not the owner of this private repo, I have been using it as part of a group for a school project, and the teacher is simply asking for the Repo's ID when sending him emails concerning anything. I'm sorry if this is blatantly obvious to a lot of people, but for the life of me I could not find any clear notes on this via github or google. I am not using a GUI for my git, strictly through a linux shell.

How do I find out the ID of the current Repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "repo ID", do you mean the URL of the repo on GitHub?

If that's what you're looking for, use `git remote`.

```
plankton:~/scraps $ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:petdance/scraps.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:petdance/scraps.git (push)
```

If you have multiple remote repos feeding into your local repository, all of them will be listed there.

Comment: Thank you. I for some odd reason assumed that I was looking for some sort of obscure integer/character combination. I think I got confused because branches or commits have those kinds of codes?

Comment: Each commit in git has a SHA1 (pronounced like "shah", without the "one" spoken).  So if you do a `git log`, each commit is uniquely identified like so: `commit 1351eb148fa6a4631d6fbc24faf95ca0be62d72f`  In many cases, it's enough to use only the first six digits of the SHA1 to uniquely identify the commit in the repo.

Answer (score 132):

If, like me, you were after the GitHub repository ID (as in - the number identifying the repo - not its name), then I found an easy way to do this via the metadata element on the main page of the repository on GitHub:

1. View the page source (Right Click > View Page Source in Chrome or Firefox for example)
2. Search the page source and look for `octolytics-dimension-repository_id`. You should find something that looks like:

   `<meta content="123456789" name="octolytics-dimension-repository_id" />`

In this example, the ID of the repository is `123456789`.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a quick query you can run in console:

`$("meta[name=octolytics-dimension-repository_id]").getAttribute('content')`

Answer (score 7):

Nine years later, using the graphql API, there is an awesome
[explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer)

1. Login
2. Paste the following query
3. Replace `repo_name`, `owner_name` with real values
4. click play

```
query {
  repository (name: *repo_name*, owner: *owner_name*)  {
        id
  }
}
```

That is all.

Comment: Plus one it works without signing in / `Personal Access Token`. Do use double quotes around `repo` and `user`

Comment: I believe the right field in the repository object is `databaseId` - not `id`

Comment: @jdgilday is right the `id` is the graphql nod id. Although it's odd the database id is the real repository id.

Answer (score 5):

Your repository on GitHub does have a unique ID and it can be obtained using the following simple bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
OWNER='your github username or organization name'
REPO_NAME='your repository name'    
gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" repos/$OWNER/$REPO_NAME | jq .id
```

Note: you will need to install both jq and github cli to get this to work.

- jq can be installed as written in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64605901/4441211
- github cli can be installed according to this link: https://cli.github.com/

Comment: Thanks  - this was (almost) exactly what I needed.  The `echo $( gh ... ) | ...` bits can just be `gh ... | jq .id` though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gh`

```bash
gh repo view OWNER/REPO --json id
```

output:

```
{
  "id": "R_kgDxxx6U7w"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way is to just open following URL in your browser.

`https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO` e.g. https://api.github.com/repos/qoomon/sandbox

The JSON response will contains the field `id` alias repository id.

Answer (score -3):

I guess he was talking about name/reponame combination (which uniquely identifies repo on github), e.g. if you using the following string in your `git remote`

```
git://github.com/sublimescala/sublime-ensime.git
```

The id will be sublimescala/sublime-ensime