# How to run jq from gitbash in windows?

Tags: bash, jq, git-bash

I have `gitbash` in Windows. I am trying to run `jq` but its giving me error.

```
$ ./jq-win64.exe 
jq 
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

*Intention*: I want to use `jq` to parse json.

Comment: The error message you're seeing there is a side effect of running it in mintty. Reported [here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1760). Running it with no arguments triggers it to read from stdin and it's trying to parse `jq` as the input.

Comment: I'm having hard time doing this. I did everything mentioned in this question and when I run jq in my git bash I get to response. anyone could help me?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Using `jq-win64.exe` from [`github.com/stedolan/jq/releases`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases), I get

```
vonc@voncav MINGW64 /d/prgs/dl
$ ./jq-win64.exe --version
jq-1.6

vonc@voncav MINGW64 /d/prgs/dl
$ echo '{"foo": 0}' | ./jq-win64.exe .
{
  "foo": 0
}
```

So it does work, but it then depends on the json document you are parsing with it.
If that json document is not well-formed, that would generate the error you see.

In your bash session, you can define (or add to your `~/.bashrc`) an alias:

```
alias jq=/path/to/jq-win64.exe
```

That way, you don't need to use `./jq`, but directly `jq`.

```
$ echo '{"foo": 0}' | jq
```

In my case:

```
vonc@voncav:/$ alias jq=/mnt/d/dwnl/jq-win64.exe
vonc@voncav:/$ echo '{"foo": 0}' | jq
{
  "foo": 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Von for the reply. How can we use just jq instead of full name - ./jq-win64.exe      eg. echo '{"foo": 0}' | jq .    Is it even possible from gitbash-windows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper Sure: use an alias. See my edited answer.

Comment: thank you, it worked like a charm.. alias is helpful for git bash..

Comment: the cli hangs indefinitely after typing: `/my/path/to/jq-win64.exe`

Comment: @kiltek Yes, that is expected: it needs some input. Without any input, it hangs, waiting to read anything from stdin. That is why the example use pipe:  `echo '{"foo": 0}' | jq`. `jq` alone would indeed hang.

Comment: On my windows machine, I run `choco install jq`.  When it finishes, I go back to my git bash terminal, without even restarting it, and `jq` is immediately available.

Comment: @User51 That would work too: I suppose the choco installation PATH is already in your USer Windows PATH (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28235975/6309)

Comment: i have alias `jq=/path/to/jq-win64.exe`  and i can run the command from git bash. now i want to use jq in a .sh script that i run in git bash, but it says jq not found?

How can i make it work in a bash script and not only from shell prompt?

Comment: @chaixdev in a script, you have a few alternatives to use your `jq` alias: https://askubuntu.com/a/98786/5470

Answer (score 163):

**Easiest solution and always latest version:**

---

run this curl in your gitbash:

```
curl -L -o /usr/bin/jq.exe https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/latest/download/jq-win64.exe
```

or manually save the `jq-win64.exe` in link above as `jq.exe` to your `/usr/bin` (which is in your git bash installation folder)

(if you are behind a proxy add the `-x proxyhost:port`)

[image]

Comment: I had problem with permissions from inside bash. I copied manually to C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin

Comment: You need administrator rights to put to  `/usr/bin/jq.exe` as this is in `Program Files`, so either save to local dir and then manually copy to `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` or start Git Bash "as Administrator"

Comment: When a configuring a Windows gitlab runner to use bash, this wasn't enough. I _also_ had to add `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` to the Windows system path, even though jq was found when typed into a normal git bash window.

Answer (score 64):

I hate answers that say you need another to use another tool to download, but using https://chocolatey.org/ made this incredibly simple for me.

From an elevated command-prompt, run:

```
choco install jq
```

`jq` magically works from bash going forward.

Comment: It works like a charm! To install choco, I used below command in an elevated PowerShell: ```Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; `
  iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))```

Comment: Hi just wondering which path I should run this command?

Comment: You "hate answers that say you need another tool to download", so your answer is to first install choco, then use that to install jq, with the added restriction that it only works if you are admin on your machine.

curl comes built into Windows as well as gitbash, requires no elevated permissions, and doesn't install crap into your machine (all of this important for CI systems!). 

Choco might be easier if you already have it anyway, but you can't pretend it requires you to download fewer additional tools.

Comment: Fair points Sven, but as I mentioned, "simple for me" and the cognitive load of knowing that jq is available through choco is extremely easy, if you have choco installed. The added benefit of using choco is that jq also works in windows command-prompt as well, not just gitbash.

Answer (score 5):

I just downloaded the binary to `%HOMEPATH%/bin/jq-win64` and it worked right away via `jq`

```
$ mkdir -p $HOMEPATH/bin
$ curl -L -o $HOMEPATH/bin/jq.exe https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/latest/download/jq-win64.exe
```

test

```
$ jq --version
jq-1.6
```

Comment: please elaborate on this.

Comment: @ChandreshMishra PATH contains $HOMEPATH/bin so this solution is fine

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/jq) (with elevated rights) you could also use [scoop.sh](https://scoop.sh/):

```sh
scoop install jq
```

Answer (score 3):

Below steps worked for me in git bash on windows 10

```
curl -L -o jq-win64.exe https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/latest/download/jq-win64.exe

export PATH=$PATH:"/C/Users/devops/Downloads/jq-win64.exe

jq --version

jq-1.6
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have fixed it in Windows10 while practicing a scenario of "Techworld with Nana" course, as per the below steps:

**1)** open "cmd" prompt (Run as administrator)

**2)** `curl -L -o /usr/bin/jq-win64.exe`
[Download it here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/latest/download/jq-win64.exe)

**3)** You can add `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` path to your environment variables. *If you follow this step, ignore the below steps.*

**[OR]**

**3)** Go to the directory where jq is downloaded: `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` and copy the file to `C:\` drive

**4)** Add the path `C:\` to "path" environment variable. This `PC-->Properties-->Advanced` system `settings --> Environment Variables -->Edit-->New`. Then add the path (where you copied jq.exe, i.e., C:) and Save it.

**5)** Now open a new "cmd" prompt, jq --version

Answer (score 2):

For windows Powershell && cmd

[Download executable](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) -> jq 1+ executables for 64-bit

Create folder in Program Files -> JQ

Copy .exe into program folder

Set environment variable to that folder

Restart terminal

Set alias

```
 Set-Alias -Name jq -Value .\jq-win64.exe
```

Run command

```
 echo '{"foo": 0}' | jq
```

Output

```
 {
    "foo": 0
 }
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

1. In windows open PowerShell as a administrator and run below command:

   `winget install jqlang.jq`
2. Once it was installed, now powershell added the .exe to the path environment variable and ask you to re-start the powershell. I would recommend you to restart you windows and then open your powershell / windows command line /  git bash cli and run below command to check the jq is properly installed or not.

   `jq --version`
3. if installed it provide the jq version.

   `$ jq --version`

   `jq-1.7-dirty`

Official installation documentation guide.
[https://jqlang.github.io/jq/download/#windows:~:text=winget%20install%20jqlang.jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/download/#windows:%7E:text=winget%20install%20jqlang.jq)