# " bash: jq: command not found" after adding jq executable file to env variable (windows)

Tags: json, bash, environment-variables, jq, git-bash

I wanted to test a json file locally with command (in bash)`curl "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" | jq`  by following this tutorial video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrjIVepRqPI

I followed each step and added the executable file in the env variable path, but not working at all, I got result:

```
$ curl "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" | jq
bash: jq: command not found

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4670    0  4670    0     0   8584      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8584
curl: (23) Failed writing body (795 != 1369)
```

Am I missing anything? Why I still got error `bash: jq: command not found`??

Comment: You have downloaded a window exe file. Execute it from a powershell or Windows command prompt

Comment: @RamanSailopal Hi I tried in CMD, it gave me error `'jq' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I can't execute `cat` either in CMD, but I can run `cat` in bash, can't run `jq`` in both bash and CMD

Comment: Are you running WSL

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can [run a `jq.exe` from git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53967916/6309).

You only need to install it in your git bash PATH:

```
curl -L -o /usr/bin/jq.exe https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/latest/download/jq-win64.exe
```

Then jq will work with your pipe command.

Comment: Hi two questions based on your answe: 1) how do I if I need to dowload win-32 or win-64? 2) how do I know which is my bash path?

Comment: @Cecilia 1/ 64 bits. 2/ `echo $PATH` (but the command mentioned already put it in the `$PATH`, since `/usr/bin` is in the `PATH`). Do all that in a git bash session.

Comment: Hi I've just resolved this issue by using `choco install jq`, it works like a chearm, but thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Cecilia No need for choco: simple curl and you are good to go.

Comment: @Cecilia thank you so much for your answer. I'd give the +1 to you: `choco install jq` works perfectly