# unable to install jq in my local windows 11 machine. Building wheel for jq (pyproject.toml) ... error

Tags: git, pip, jq

$pip install jq
Collecting jq
Using cached jq-1.4.1.tar.gz (2.7 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: jq
Building wheel for jq (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for jq (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [5 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
Executing: ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --prefix=C:\Users\SaiTejaMakani\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_7jksk26\jq_bc859a8c4bf54fa0a70720ec3ecd5114_deps\build\onig-install-6.9.4
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for jq
Failed to build jq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for jq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.2 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

I have created anempty setup.py in my project to tryitbut no luck. Havent found any solution so far.

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ — please note this the original `jq` written in C while `pip install jq` installs Python wrapper for it and the wrapper seems to be Unix-only. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjq%5D+windows

Comment: I am able to solve it by installing it bash first and then following the curl command on the below stack overflow answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64605901/9727676
curl -L -o /usr/bin/jq.exe https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/latest/download/jq-win64.exe